# How to update XML node occurring multiple times in XML of DB2 table structure?

Tags: sql, db2

We are facing an issue with DB2 SQL. We are trying to check if we can get a solution to this.

Problem Statement:

1. Writing a SQL to update an XML node which occurs multiple times in nested form depending on some condition. 
   Below is the XML structure. `<RFPData>` is the root node.

```xml
<RFPData>
.
.
.
.
<class dataStr="list">
                .
.
.
</class >
<class dataStr="list">
    <classCheckedProductStr>Life &amp;lt;br/&amp;gt;Dental &amp;lt;br/&amp;gt;</classCheckedProductStr>
    <classDescriptionOptionText>All Active Full-Time Assistant Vice Presidents</classDescriptionOptionText>
    <classDescriptionOption>5</classDescriptionOption>
    <life>
        <ClsLifePayPeriod>W</ClsLifePayPeriod>
        <coverage dataStr="list">
           <status>ACTIVE</status>
            <coverageId>50</coverageId>
            <coverageName>Buy Up Life with AD&amp;D</coverageName>
            <ClassLifeBasicLifeEmployee>22</ClassLifeBasicLifeEmployee>
            <covId>50</covId>
            <ClassLifeBasicLifeDependents>34</ClassLifeBasicLifeDependents>
            <isCoverageSelected>Y</isCoverageSelected>
            <SQ>0</SQ>
        </coverage>
        <coverage dataStr="list">
            <status>ACTIVE</status>
            <coverageId>54</coverageId>
            <coverageName>Buy Up Dependent Life with AD&amp;D</coverageName>
            <ClassLifeBasicLifeEmployee>44</ClassLifeBasicLifeEmployee>
            <covId>54</covId>
            <ClassLifeBasicLifeDependents>43</ClassLifeBasicLifeDependents>
            <isCoverageSelected>Y</isCoverageSelected>
            <SQ>1</SQ>
        </coverage>
        <clsFutureEmpWaitingPeriodRule>1STFLWP</clsFutureEmpWaitingPeriodRule>
        <clsCurrentEmpWaitingPeriodRule>1STFLWP</clsCurrentEmpWaitingPeriodRule>
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
        <clsCurrentEmpAveragedOver>-1</clsCurrentEmpAveragedOver>
        <isCoverageChecked>Y</isCoverageChecked>
        <clsCurrentEmpEarningsDefinition>-1</clsCurrentEmpEarningsDefinition>
        <clsFutureEmpWaitingPeriodUnit>DY</clsFutureEmpWaitingPeriodUnit>
        <ClsCurrentEmpLifeWaitingPeriodValue>14</ClsCurrentEmpLifeWaitingPeriodValue>
        <clsCurrentEmpWaitingPeriodUnit>DY</clsCurrentEmpWaitingPeriodUnit>
        <ClsLifeHoursWorked>12</ClsLifeHoursWorked>
        <ClsFutureEmpLifeWaitingPeriodValue>33</ClsFutureEmpLifeWaitingPeriodValue>
    </life>
    <SQ>0</SQ>
</class>
<class dataStr="list">
                .
.
.
</class >
.
.
.
.
</RFPData>
```

2. The `<classDescriptionOption>` node highlighted in Blue above needs to be updated to a value say 6 if `<classDescriptionOptionText>` node value is “All Active Full-Time Supervisors”.
3. But we are not able to achieve this as there could be multiple `<class dataStr="list">` in which `<classDescriptionOption>` could be present.
4. When we wrote the SQL script it updated all the occurrences with the value 6 which we provide in update statement, even if we try to compare with equating `<classDescriptionOptionText>` value as “All Active Full-Time Supervisors”.

Update script used is as below.

```
UPDATE T_SL_APP
SET SL_XML_TXT = XMLQUERY('
copy $new := $SL_XML_TXT
modify (
for $i in $new/RFPData/classSetup/class/classDescriptionOption  return
do replace value of $i with "6"
)
return $new')
WHERE SL_APP_ID = '1184'
and xmlexists('$SL_XML_TXT//RFPData/classSetup/class[classDescriptionOptionText = "All Active Full-Time Supervisors"]');
```

So can someone please help us to resolve. The entire structure of XML is attached for reference.

Comment: Have you tried adding the required predicates into the XQuery, i.e., inside the "for" expression? The xmlexists is a test to find qualifying documents, but the nodes to update are found inside the XQuery expression.

Comment: @data_henrik That is what I am not able to do. Can you please suggest and give a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but try to use a predicate within the XQuery:

```
copy $new := $SL_XML_TXT
modify (
     for $i in $new/RFPData/classSetup/class[classDescriptionOptionText = "All Active Full-Time Supervisors"]/classDescriptionOption   
     return
         do replace value of $i with "6"
       )
return $new
```

The above would only iterate over those "class" nodes that have the OptionText with the Supervisors, access the Option and update it.